# How to handle 2 different versions of HttpServletRequest in Java7?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I'm developing a REST server under NetBeans 7.4 on Windows (with Java SE Runtime 1.7.0_21-b11)
The .war is then deployed on a Linux machine running Tomcat (Java 1.7.0_45-b18) with a TeamCity automated build using ant to build the .war

I am trying to unit test the REST methods using a custom built class implementing HttpServletRequest that only implements a couple of methods.

```
public class HttpMockReq implements HttpServletRequest { @Override ... }
```

My issue is that the definition of that interface is different in my dev environment in Windows and when I compile it with ant on Linux. Specifically, 3 methods are defined in the HttpServletRequest on Windows which do not exist in the Linux version:

```
changeSessionId, 
upgrade
```

and

```
setContentLength
```

and the Linux build complains that I do not override anything with these (fake) methods.

I actually have the same issue with HttpServletResponse with

```
setContentLengthLong
```

I'm a bit lost with the different libraries, tools and java installation. I can't figure out how/why the windows side (which has a slightly older version of Java 7) has a more extensive definition of these interfaces.

Side question: is there a way to make one of these environment accept the richer or poorer implementation with @Ignore or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your problem is the version of Tomcat you're using. The method `changeSessionId()` is from the **Servlets 3.1 spec**, which is supported only for Tomcat 8.0.X, maybe you have Tomcat 7.0.X installed instead, check it out and if true then try downloading and installing Tomcat 8.0.X (see http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)

Comment: That's it indeed. Is there a way to ask Netbeans on the Windows side to use the older Servlet spec?

Comment: In order to address the issue given my context, the fix was to explicitly add the servlet-api.jar from Tomcat7 into the NetBeans project's list of jars. This takes precedence over the j2ee-platform-classpath, and my mock was very happy.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than implement the interface, consider extending [HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html). If you need to be able to implement different, incompatible interface versions, consider [creating a proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D,%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler%29).

Since this is for unit tests, consider a [mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) framework like [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/).